# ASP.NET MVC small project architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I read a lot all around but I could not find clear answer to the question of best practice ASP.NET MVC project separation. I have quite small, one man show project, I want to have object-relational mapped database, using Entity Framework, but I would like to avoid separating database layer to another project. As I know, is not good idea to put data models to implicit Model folder of MVC project, but where to put it? What shloud be the correct naming and situation of View models (in Model folder I gues), edmx file, interfaces, repositories, what is the best place to put whole business logic?

**EDIT**

I expressed myself wrong with the separating DAL to another project, it´s not important for me to have or not to have DAL in separate project, I just don´t see any advantage of this approach in project of that size.

Comment: What's wrong with having the DAL in a separate project?

Comment: Nothing at all, I just don´t see any advantages of that approach in project of that size. I expressed myself wrong, it´s not important for me to have or not to have DAL in separate project.

Answer (score 4):

What if your one man show project becomes a big project over time? By not separating concerns you've lost scalability immediately.

I wouldn't put anything in the MVC project that isn't directly related to presenting or editing data on the client.

Think about a service layer which has the responsibility of communicating the the database.
Think about a domain layer which describes your entities. You could then construct your view models from domain entities, which are retrieved via your service layer.

That's a very basic architecture. If you have, say 4 tables in your database, that's 4 domain entities (models or whatever you want to call them), 4 EF configuration files and 4 view models to show the data on a page. If you then decide to add another few tables in your database, your MVC project starts to get quite big, and that's without mentioning any interfaces or services yet which would handle the CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-fundamentals) by default has only 2 naming conventions (which anyway, can be changed):

1. Controllers are placed into the Controllers folder and their names should end with 'Controller' word like 'ShoppingChartController'.
2. Views are placed into the subfolders (which name are the same as your controller name) of the Views folder and again, by default, their names are the same as action name of your controller.

The reason of that is by default the MVC framework looks for controllers and views in these folders (actually there is a more complex logic to look for them but the rest you can get from the web site I've mentioned above and from MSDN).

As for the models - it's totally doesn't matter. As for me, if I need to create an extremely simple web site then I put ViewModels into the ViewModels folder and name them like 'ShoppingChartViewModel' and the data models, which are mapped to the appropriate tables in the database, into the Models folder.
If you have services or something else that has business logic incapsulated, then you can put them into a 'Services' folder.